# SAPI fatal error: crtdbg.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, windows, sapi

I am building a voice assistant using Microsoft SAPI in C++ .
I used the code from Cyril Leroux's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16547349/sapi-speech-to-text-example)

But during compilation, it throws this error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Speech SDK 5.1\Include\sphelper.h:17:20: fatal error: crtdbg.h: No such file or directory
 #include <crtdbg.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
```

I would be grateful if someone could help.

Comment: I have that file both in my Visual Studio folder and in the Windows Kits SDK folder. What are you compiling this with?

Comment: Also some suggestions for replacing it if you're using MingW here: [How do I get crtdbg.h file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12685202/243245)